# Code gives no output on console

Tags: c

I am running the below code but getting no output on console screen. Please Explain:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    enum days {sun,mon,tue,wed,thru,fri,sat};
}
```

Comment: You dint write anything on console. try `printf("Hello world!\n");`

Comment: you havent printed anything . How can you expect the output to come on screen :)

Comment: Welcome to C programming world !
http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/p/enumeration.htm

Comment: `#include <stdio.h> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { printf("Hello World\n"); return 0; }`

Comment: Did the tutorial you followed (sorry for my random assumption) say anything about an output?? [This seems a good start](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm)

Comment: @SuvP thanks yar i got good tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("sun, mon, tue, wed, thru, fri, sat\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: Adding a `\n` in the end is better, because `stdout` is line buffered.

Comment: no i was trying to print all days by the value sun=1,mon=2 ... sat=7. like these.

Comment: @UmeshHs: Refer to Amarnath Krishnan's answer then, that's how you do this.

Comment: @UmeshHs: And just FYI: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf

Answer (score 2):

enum is used as an userdefined datatype. you can create your own datatype using following syntax. enum can be used to setup collection of named integer constants.

```
enum datatype_name {val1,val2,val3,...,valN};
```

By default enum value will be generated from 0. Here,

```
val1=0; //val1 is a named constant holding value 0
val2=1; //val2 is a named constant holding value 1
valN=N-1; //valN is a named constant holding value N-1
```

check the following code for default enum  behaviour.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//Define user defined data type. Here days is the datatype. sun,mon,...,sat are named constants.
enum days{sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat}; 
int main()
{
   printf("%d",wed); //wed is a named constant with default value 3
   return 0;
}
Output: 3
```

Initializing custom value for enum.

```
#include<stdio.h>
enum days{sum=100,mon=200,tue=300,wed=400,thu=500,fri=600,sat=700};
int main()
{
   printf("%d",wed); //wed is a named constant with user defined value 400
   return 0;
}
Output: 400
```

You can create a enumeration for boolean.

```
enum boolean{ false,true};
int main()
{
   printf("false=%d",false); //false is constant that holds default value 0
   printf("\ntrue=%d",true); //true is constant that holds default value 1
   return 0;
}
Output: 
  false=0
  true=1
```

Comment: Last example may cause compilation-time error if someone also includes C99 stdbool.h where false and true are defined as macros (0 and 1) I think.

Comment: @maverik was right. Its just an alternative to use stdbool.h.